# Drawing an X in a 2D array - Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have to make a an empty 2D array, given the number of rows and columns. The empty array is shown empty by having underscores so this would be an example of an empty array (those are 4 underscores per line):

```
____
____
____
```

Below is my code to make this:

```
def gen_table (rows, columns):
    matrix = [["_"] * columns for _i in range(rows)]

    return matrix
```

So what I want to do is be able to draw an X in the array to look like this,

```
S___S
_S_S_
__S__
_S_S_
s___S

Z__Z
_ZZ_
_ZZ_
Z__Z
____
```

I have tried multiple things, such as trying to pop at the locations where I want to put an "s" but nothing seemed to be working.

Any idea how I can accomplish drawing an X in the array?

Comment: please post the code you tried ... also post what the output of it is, and what you expected the output to be

Comment: I think a good start would be writing code that prints the indexes of the "array" that must be changed. Have you done that?

Comment: `def gen_table(rows, columns): m = min(rows, columns); return [['X' if i == j or i+j == m else '_' for j in range(columns)] for i in range(rows)]`

Comment: Hint: `x` and `-x-1` gets the `x`th and `x`th-to-last items in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok lets take a look at this

```
nrows = 5
ncols = 5
mark = "X"
space = "_"
the_matrix = []
```

sets up all our variables now lets do our thing

```
for i in range(nrows//2): #loop through the first half of rows
    the_matrix.append([space]*ncols) # the default row
    idx1,idx2 = i , ncols - 1 - i  #left and right indexes
    the_matrix[-1][idx1] = the_matrix[-1][idx2] = mark #set our indices
```

there you go you now have half an X ... I will leave it as an exercise for you to figure out the bottom half

Comment: If nrows is odd, say 5, 5/2 would give a float. I get the error: "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Answer (score 2):

If the matrix is always a square matrix with odd dimensions, then:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> def gen_table (rows, columns):
        matrix = [["_"] * columns for _i in range(rows)]
        #Indexes of first diagonal
        diag1 = [(i, i) for i in xrange(rows)]
        #Indexes of second diagonal
        diag2 = [(rows-i-1, i) for i in xrange(rows)]
        #Iterate over the indexes from diag1 and diag2 and modify matrix
        for i, j in diag1 + diag2:
            matrix[i][j] = 'S'
        return matrix
...     
>>> pprint(gen_table(5,5))
[['S', '_', '_', '_', 'S'],
 ['_', 'S', '_', 'S', '_'],
 ['_', '_', 'S', '_', '_'],
 ['_', 'S', '_', 'S', '_'],
 ['S', '_', '_', '_', 'S']]
>>> pprint(gen_table(7,7))
[['S', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'S'],
 ['_', 'S', '_', '_', '_', 'S', '_'],
 ['_', '_', 'S', '_', 'S', '_', '_'],
 ['_', '_', '_', 'S', '_', '_', '_'],
 ['_', '_', 'S', '_', 'S', '_', '_'],
 ['_', 'S', '_', '_', '_', 'S', '_'],
 ['S', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'S']]
```

Output for square matrix with even dimensions:

```
>>> pprint(gen_table(6,6))
[['S', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'S'],
 ['_', 'S', '_', '_', 'S', '_'],
 ['_', '_', 'S', 'S', '_', '_'],
 ['_', '_', 'S', 'S', '_', '_'],
 ['_', 'S', '_', '_', 'S', '_'],
 ['S', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'S']]
```

Comment: I think this will work for even numbered matrices also ... at least per problem description

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, but for even numbers it's impossible to get a perfect `X`.

Comment: meh he has an example output for even numbers and Im pretty sure yours matches expected :P

Comment: as an aside i think `(x,y) for x,y in zip(range(nrows),range(ncols))` would be marginally better +1 all the same I like this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
print("*" * 10) # to let you see any errors 
input_size = int(input("Minimum of 3 lines. How many lines do you want to see : "))
size = (3 + input_size - 3) 
i = 0 
j = (input_size - 1) 
for row in range(size) : 
    for col in range(size) :
        if row == i and col == j : 
            print("*", end = "") 
            j -= 1
            i += 1 
        elif row == col :
            print("*", end = "")
        else :
            print(end = " ")
    print()
```